# git- not able to pull from gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm pretty new to Linux environment and git.

I have a (private) project in gitlab to which I need to push/pull changes.

Let's say my local working copy is the following directory

```
/home/iamme/Desktop/Development/local_gitlab_copy/
```

I added my username and email like this, which worked perfectly

```
git config --global user.name testusername
git config --global user.email testemail@email.com
```

There are 2 branches in my gitlab project
1) master
2) test

I'm trying to checkout master to my local folder

I gave

```
git checkout master
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error

Can anyone tell me why I am seeing such an error?

Comment: Did you `git clone <url> local_gitlab_copy` the repository? If so, where did you try to run `git checkout master`?

Answer (score 1):

It means

`/home/iamme/Desktop/Development/local_gitlab_copy/'

does not contain .git folder in it.

I suggest you do.

```
/home/iamme/Desktop/Development/local_gitlab_copy/ $ls
```

and see any sub directory for the project. and then by

```
/home/iamme/Desktop/Development/local_gitlab_copy/ cd directory_name
```

you can again proceed.

If you yet have not clone then,

run,

```
/home/iamme/Desktop/Development/local_gitlab_copy/ $git clone <url>
```